# Can't boot into Ubuntu-- unable to mount root

Tags: boot, kernel

I have been successfully dual booting with Windows and Ubuntu 23.10 for about two months. I first installed Ubuntu 22.04 but I wasn't able to boot it with my hardware (I think the AMD 7800xt is the issue).  After installing 23.10, I was able to boot and use Ubuntu.

Today, without any updates that I noticed, I am no longer able to boot 23.10 normally (nor am I able to boot into 6.5.0.14 or 6.5.0.10 recovery kernels.

The error I get trying to boot these options:

```
Can't open blockdev  
...  
Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)  ...
```

I am however able to use the 6.5.0.10 generic kernel.  When I boot from that kernel and run sudo apt update and install I get many errors the ones below.  I am not sure if they are related to my failure to mount.

```
Building module:  
Cleaning build area...(bad exit status: 2)  
make -j12 KERNELRELEASE=6.5.0-14-generic TTM_NAME=amdttm SCHED_NAME=amd-sched -C
 /lib/modules/6.5.0-14-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.2.4-1664922.22.04/
build...(bad exit status: 2)  
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/amdgpu-dkms.0.c
rash'  
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-14-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.2.4-1664922.22.04/build/make.log for more informa
tion.
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-14-generic/x86_64 succeeded for 8812au  
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-14-generic/x86_64 failed for amdgpu(10)  
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.    
Refer to previous errors for more information.    
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.5.0-14-generic
   ...fail!  
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11  
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic (--configure):  
 installed linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic package post-installation script subproc
ess returned error exit status 1  
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already  
                                                              Errors were encoun
tered while processing:  
 linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic    
 amdgpu-dkms    
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04  
 linux-generic-hwe-22.04  
 linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging I found that the package rocM was causing an issue with the software updater. After removing that package, I am able to boot again.